# How to count each vehicle only once in Traffic vehicle counter?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, increment, yolo

I am using yolov4 and opencv to detect vehicles and track them in a sample video. But the problem is that before my code just took one car and considered it as a new car in every next frame as it went through the video and it incremented 1 to the car count. So, only one car was getting counted 5 or 6 times. Then I tried this method:

```
if 387<bbox[0]<400: # bbox[0] is the top left coordinate of the car's bounding box
    car_count += 1 # if the top left coordinate of the car's bounding box is within the range, then increment 1 to car_count
```

In short, I fixed a range for the car to get detected. But in that too, if the car still goes slower, or if it doesn't pass the range within 1 frame the car gets counted twice. And if I narrow the range, in 15-20 fps sometimes if a car misses the detection range or the car just goes too fast, then the car_counter doesn't get incremented by 1. So, any idea how I can solve this problem ?

A sample Image:

[image: A sample image]

The area between the 2 red lines is the range of detection for the frame in the sample image.
So, can I just get the car to get detected only once after it enters the range of detection or something like that ?

Update: I just figured out how I can draw circles at the middle of the bounding box of a car. So I can get the middle point of each bounding box.
I did that by using:

```
import numpy as np
# coor[0], coor[1], coor[2], coor[3] = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax); 4 points of a bounding box
x, y = (coor[0]+coor[2]) // 2, (coor[1]+coor[3]) // 2
x = np.round(x).astype("int")
y = np.round(y).astype("int")
cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 10, (255, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
```

I think we can just track these middle points instead tracking one corner of the bounding box.

Image with center circle in the bounding box

[image: Image with centre circle]

The yellow circle on the car is the center of the bounding box.

**EDIT**: Here is the script:

```
x, y = (coor[0]+coor[2]) // 2, (coor[1]+coor[3]) // 2
x = np.round(x).astype("int")
y = np.round(y).astype("int")
if class_name == 'car':
    if 390.0<x<400.0:
        car_count += 1
        with open("results.txt", "a") as result_file:
            result_file.write(f"Cars: {car_count};Motorbikes: {motorbike_count};Bicycles: {bicycle_count};Trucks: {truck_count}\n")
        print("Car detected !")

if class_name == 'motorbike':
    if 390.0<x<400.0:
        motorbike_count += 1
        with open("results.txt", "a") as result_file:
            result_file.write(f"Cars: {car_count};Motorbikes: {motorbike_count};Bicycles: {bicycle_count};Trucks: {truck_count}\n")
        print("Motorbike detected !")

if class_name == 'bicycle':
    if 390.0<x<400.0:
        bicycle_count += 1
        with open("results.txt", "a") as result_file:
            result_file.write(f"Cars: {car_count};Motorbikes: {motorbike_count};Bicycles: {bicycle_count};Trucks: {truck_count}\n")
        print("Bicycle detected !")

if class_name == 'truck':
    if 390.0<x<400.0:
        truck_count += 1
        with open("results.txt", "a") as result_file:
            result_file.write(f"Cars: {car_count};Motorbikes: {motorbike_count};Bicycles: {bicycle_count};Trucks: {truck_count}\n")
        print("Truck detected !")
```

It is kind of a script that gives cumulative counting of the cars or vehicles.

**2nd EDIT**: I am running this in google colab, and I get 27-30 FPS in it. And I just checked the centroid positions, they differ by approx. 10 in each frame. eg. In the previous frame: x: 682, In the next frame: x: between 673-671

**3rd EDIT**: I really think that we should just take one vehicle and set it's value to not_counted. And once it passes the line, It's value will be is_counted. And if the value is is_counted, then it won't count the same vehicle again. This probably can help solve the problem. But the question now is that how to define this value to each of the detected object. Here is the github link to the whole code that I am using...

[Link to the Repo](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-custom-functions)

If anyone can figure out the answers, then please let me know. Just hoping for a solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To do this successfully you need a proper object tracking algorithm. Look up for centroid minimum distance. This might help you https://github.com/lev1khachatryan/Centroid-Based_Object_Tracking

Comment: I think assigning a unique ID to each tracked object and then checking the ID when the car or vehicle enters the detection region can be a way to avoid detecting single car twice.

Answer (score 1):

for this purpose, you need a tracker. tracked will give each detected object an id and you can check the area with the tracker id. my suggestion is the [DeepSort](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort) because it is compatible completely with YOLO and there are a lot of examples of the combination of these two.
[Here](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort) is an example of the combination of deep sort and YOLO.
as you can see, each item has an id which you access easily.

Comment: Can you please give like a code example of it ?

Comment: @Just_A_Coder I edit the answer and append an example for you. hope it helps.

Comment: @Just_A_Coder was it useful?